# scraping dynamic content with scrapy and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

My requirement  -  There are number of urls provided in the excel file which i have to scrape one by one and extract the text part on the urls and load into the DB.  I have already able to read the file, one by one, scrape all the urls in the excel file (only the urls given in the file not the child pages). I have used flask and scrapy for it, but the question is that there are number of web urls where data is loaded dynamically and scrapy is not able to fetch the text part so i have tried splash which is also not working for my dynamically loaded text. Right now, i am trying with selenium but it is also not giving me output in which i am trying to take the screenshot and then will read the image and extract the text part.Anybody can show the simple example how can do it with selenium and any other way? Below is the code which i am using -

```
import scrapy
import lxml.html.clean
import re
import w3lib.html
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Sequence
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, String, MetaData, Integer, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
import difflib
from w3lib.html import remove_tags, remove_tags_with_content
from .comparison_data import PageContentComparison
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = "quotes"
   def __init__(self):
     self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
     self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

   def start_requests(self):
      urls = [
        'https://www.analog.com/en/products/landing-pages/new-products-listing.html',
       # 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
    ]
      for url in urls:
        #yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
        yield SeleniumRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse,screenshot=True,script='window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')

  def parse(self, response):
   # self.driver.get(response.url)
   # self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
  #  scroll_until_loaded(self)

    with open('image.jpeg', 'wb') as image_file:
       image_file.write(response.meta['screenshot'])
```